# Ubuntu terminal freezes with FFmpeg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, mono-framework

My Linux server runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

Whenever I try to launch ffmpeg with certain arguments:

```
"ffmpeg -i /home/robbert/Downloads/closer.mp3 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 pipe:1"
```

It just freezes on 00:00:00:27. The full console output is: http://pastebin.com/77YY9N7j

I have been stuck on this issue for about a week now and I really can't seem to get it working.
I am using Mono-framework to run my app since its coded in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The console output is the "error" one. The output of *ffmpeg* seemed to be piped. Your *reader* process may be stuck.

You might read validated answer to [SO-article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28818956/425540) (c#) if you're using multiple pipes. Briefly, you may experience deadlock or full pipe-buffer (then deadlock...).

As the input is not real-time, a temporary file can circumvent this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I will look into this and I will update this post if this is the right solution!

Comment: But do you by any chance have an explanation why it is working on windows and not on linux?